# What happens if there is both a tapped and untapped Archelos, Lagoon Mystic on the battlefield? (Commander Legends spoilers)

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Archelos, Lagoon Mystic](https://www.magicspoiler.com/mtg-spoiler/archelos-lagoon-mystic/) is a creature recently spoiled in the Commander Legends set.

[image]

Archelos has two abilities on him.

> As long as Archelos, Lagoon Mystic is tapped, other permanents enter the battlefield tapped.

> As long as Archelos is untapped, other permanents enter the battlefield untapped.

What happens if there are two Archeloses on the battlefield, one tapped and one untapped?

Comment: The obvious answer here is "one of them is moved to the graveyard as a state-based action due to the legend rule". Are you asking about other permanents which enter the battlefield at the same time as the second copy, or if not what mechanism are you using to get around the legend rule?

Comment: Honestly, pick one.  Each turtle is controlled by different players, or I have a Mirror Gallery on the field.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Legend rule only applies to being controlled by the same player now, there can be two copies of legendary permanents on the battlefield with separate controllers. The question is about the interaction between the two replacement effects on entering tapped vs untapped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These would be 2 different replacement effects, so the player whose permanent is entering the battlefield would choose one to apply first, and would then apply the other (so only the second one they chose would end up mattering):

> 614.1d Continuous effects that read “[This permanent] enters the battlefield . . .” or “[Objects] enter the battlefield . . .” are replacement effects.

> 616.1. If two or more replacement and/or prevention effects are attempting to modify the way an event affects an object or player, the affected object’s controller (or its owner if it has no controller) or the affected player chooses one to apply, following the steps listed below.

> > 616.1e Once the chosen effect has been applied, this process is repeated (taking into account only replacement or prevention effects that would now be applicable) until there are no more left to apply.

Comment: Interesting, I would have thought it would go in timestamp order depending on which Archelos entered the battlefield first, but I forgot about replacement effects, which then makes sense that you would pick.  So, effectively, having multiple Archelos doesn't matter as long as one is untapped.